# localization based on TDOA

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, localization

To locate a transmitter, I use a localization based on TDOA(Chan's method) with 3 receivers. The results obtained are not effective. What is a possible solution to improve the localization accuracy without adding additional receivers?

Comment: Chan's method comes with good error bounds in the original publication. Have you checked your performance against these? If you're not close to them, your implementation is buggy / too approximative. If you are close, you *will* have to add more information to your observation. Because you're not sharing anything about your actual implementation, it's impossible for us to know what could be improved (if it can be improved, at all).